# How to deploy Angular2 app develop using angular-cli and NodeJS on tomcat

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular(1 or 2). I have built a small application using Angular-cli and running on NodeJs. But my production env is using Tomcat. Is there a way to do it without making lots of changes in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Angular project is just JavaScript/TypeScript and HTML. You can deploy it on any web server by simply coping the files. Or you can use something like WebPack to minify/bundle everything into single JavaScript and HTML files, and copy that to your web server.

Comment: This is not true if you are using the angular router, which seems to only run under NodeJs at this time. Correct me if I am wrong. It is a big problem for me.

Comment: I don't think that is true. I'm using RC1 currently (using the now deprecated router) and I've tested the new router in RC4 running under IIS and it works fine.

Comment: I have a menu with [routerLink] in HTML A tags. When I run it from "npm start", it all loads and works fine, usually showing "localhost:3000" in the browser address bar. When I try to access the application from a browser without running it from "npm start", the page stops being generated at the point where it encounters the [routerLink].

Comment: That could be caused by tons of other issues, not Node vs. Tomact. It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing your app.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. So I looked into the matter with F12 on Chrome and discovered that after the base href="/" in the HTML, none of my scripts could be found for some reason. On a hunch, I removed the slash and set base href="" and everything worked!

Comment: There you go. I should have suggested to check the baseUrl. In dev mode i'm usin "/" but in production mode I have to set it to the /SubDirectory/App/ where the app is actually running from. Plus, in IIS, I have to have Re-write rules configured so it would serve everything properly. Worth a blog post sometimes.

Comment: Thanks Boyan for quick reply. So here is what I did:

Comment: Thanks Boyan for quick reply. So here is what I did: I created dynamic web project in eclipse, copied app and vendor folders into WebContent folder, copied index.html, main.js, main.js.map, system-config.js, sys-config.js.map into WebContent dir also. my web.xml has index.html. I tried to launch it on Tomcat 8. it is only displaying "Loading..". It is not recognizing <my_app></my_app> tag and thus not loading what is in the my_app.component.js. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Hit me up if you find out anything @Jpatel , currently undergoing the same process

Comment: Can you post your index.html? Did you copy all the angular2 files from node_modules? Did you bring up the dev tools in chrome and see if it gives you any errors in the console?

Comment: finally got it. it was my index.html generated via angular cli. I had to move all my scripts in the head section. So index.html created by angular cli seems not working with Tomcat. I used index.html from the Quick Start.

Comment: @Jpatel if you solved your question can you please post the answer with the steps you undertook? This would be beneficial to other people like me facing the same issue. thanks

Comment: @nuvio if you are using angular cli, you will have hard time doing it. I used Angular Quick Start to create my project and index.html. Keep body of the index.html very simple. I only have tag for my app component. Once you have working app, create java web application using Eclipse. Copy all your .html,  .js and .map files to appropriate folder under WebContent folder.  I had it working with only one html page. after that I did not try. hope this helps.

Comment: There is nothing hard about this even when you are using the angular-cli. Once the CLI creates the release build, you have your HTML and JS files and you do the same thing you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I see many people asking for the answer. Here are the steps which are working now.

1. Create your project using CLI.
2. Once you have working project, go to your project folder in command window and build using `ng build --prod`
3. All your built files will be in dist folder.
4. Copy all the files from dist folder to the webapps folder of Tomcat.
   This is the most important step. Without this you will only see "Loading..."
5. In index.html, change `<base href="/">` to `<base href=".">`